# Permutation or combination with replacement

Tags: combinatorics

If I give 3 candies to 8 kids where i can give more than one candy to any given kid is this combination or permutation?

Comment: Once you give a kid one or more candies (and they immediately eat it/them), can it be replaced???  There's no replacement here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: Depends - are the candies distinct? E.g. if two kid swap a piece of candy, does that change the distribution of candies?

Comment: I think the idea of replacement comes from kids being able to receive more than one piece of candy. The candy is not distinguishable. I thought it was a combination with replacement. My prof says it is a permutation with replacement but I cannot see how order matters!

Comment: Ok, sorry, but I was wrong at first. the actual answer is slightly different then what I originally put, see my edited answer before for the correct explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a confusing question since this does not specifically count order or not. We have to go back to the basics to figure this out.

What are we doing here: First we find all different permutations for 3 candies:

1. Give all three to someone: 3
2. Give one person 1 and another person 2: 2 1
3. Give 3 people 1 each: 1 1 1

these are unique permutations where order DOES NOT MATTER. For the first case we use combinations to choose 1 person at random out of the 8 people, and then we give the candies out in order, although it doesn't matter here.

In the second case, we choose 2 people at random out of the 8 people (combinations), then we hand it out in order. (for example, adam getting 1 and bob getting 2 is not the same as bob getting 1 and adam getting 2)

Finally, in the third case, we choose 3 people at random out of the 8 people, but giving it out in order would count each scenario 6 times, so we divide by 6. (Notice this is not combinations, but instead permutation where we end up dividing by the exact number for it to resemble a combination)

Therefore, while the basic method we would use to solve this problem includes both permutation and combination, I would lean toward this problem using permutation if I had to choose one or the other since the permutation is more important, and the combination part could be slightly unnecessary as well.